# Adding commas when necessary to a csv file using regex

Tags: regex, vim, awk

I have a csv file like the following:

```
entity_name,data_field_name,type
Unit,id
Track,id,LONG
```

The second row is missing a comma. I wonder if there might be some regex or awk like tool in order to append commas to the end of line in case there are missing commas in these rows?

### Update

I know the requirements are a little vague. There might be several alternative ways to narrow down the requirements such as:

1. The header row should define the number of columns (and commas) that is valid for the whole file. The script should read the header row first and find out the correct number of columns.
2. The number of columns might be passed as an argument to the script.
3. The number of columns can be hardcoded into the script.

I didn't narrow down the requirements at first because I was ok with any of them. Of course, the first alternative is the best but I wasn't sure if this was easy to implement or not.

Thanks for all the great answers and comments. Next time, I will state acceptable alternative requirements explicitly.

Comment: you tagged Q with vim, you don't know how to add the comma on line 2 in vim? or there are still more requirements?

Comment: Could be as simple as `v/,.*,/norm A,`

Comment: Edit your question to show your attempt and expected output. Can there by 2 missing commas? blank lines? If so update your input to include those cases.

Comment: @Kent In the question, I said "there might be some regex or awk like tool". It is very common in this kind of problems that someone suggests a very different solution with some other tool. Vim is a very powerful tool. I thought maybe there might come out an interesting solution using Vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk command to fill up all rows starting from 2nd row with the empty cell values based on # of columns in the header row, in order to avoid hard-coding # of columns:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{nc=NF} NF{$nc=$nc} 1' file

entity_name,data_field_name,type
Unit,id,
Track,id,LONG
```

Earlier solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{nc=NF} {printf "%s", $0;
  for (i=NF+1; i<=nc; i++) printf "%s", OFS; print ""}' file
```

Comment: `awk -F, -vOFS=, 'NR==1{x=NF}NF=x'` does the same.

Comment: Actually I did that once but got a word of caution from EdMorton that this feature of changing `NF` is not portable across all the awk versions.

Comment: Do you know which version(s)? It has always worked for me.

Comment: I currently have gnu awk, but will try on BSD awk in few hours

Comment: @123: Just tested on OSX's `awk` and `awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1{x=NF}NF=x' file` didn't work. 2nd row prints as `Unit,id` instead of `Unit,id,`

Comment: Nice, thanks for the follow up. I think `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$3=$3}1` should also work then ?

Comment: Yes `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{nc=NF} NF{$nc=$nc} 1' file` worked (avoided hardcoding # of columns)

Comment: So far you've shown those 2 approaches work in 2 awks (gawk and BSD awk). FWIW I'm not convinced that you aren't wading in Undefined Behavior waters but the gawk manual at least does document that the `$3=$3` approach will do what you show it does and and it doesn't say anything about it being gawk-specific so it's probably safe. The assigning to NF thing I think is hit or miss.

Comment: [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) says `$3=$3` will work as you show: `assigning to a nonexistent field (for example, $(NF+2)=5) shall increase the value of NF; create any intervening fields with the uninitialized value; and cause the value of $0 to be recomputed, with the fields being separated by the value of OFS.` Can't find anything in POSIX about what happens when you assign to NF so I think that is UB.

Comment: Wow thanks @EdMorton for confirming that. I knew for sure that merely setting `NF` to higher value doesn't wok on all awk but it is good to know that `$nc=$nc` will do the needful and **cause the value of `$0` to be recomputed with new empty fields separated by `OFS`**

Answer (score 1):

I would use sed,

```
sed 's/^[^,]*,[^,]*$/&,/' file
```

*Example:*

```
$ echo 'Unit,id' | sed 's/^[^,]*,[^,]*$/&,/'
Unit,id,
$ echo 'Unit,id,bar' | sed 's/^[^,]*,[^,]*$/&,/'
Unit,id,bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ awk -F , 'NF==2{$2=$2","}1' file
```

**Output:**

```
entity_name,data_field_name,type
Unit,id,
Track,id,LONG
```

Answer (score 1):

With another `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NF==2{$3=""}1' OFS=, yourfile.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

to present balance to all the awk solutions, following could be a vim only solution

```
:v/,.*,/norm A,
```

rationale

```
/,.*,/          searches for 2 comma's in a line
:v              apply a global command on each line NOT matching the search
norm A,         enters normal mode and appends a , to the end of the line
```

Answer (score 1):

This MIGHT be all you need, depending on the info you haven't shared with us in your question:

```
$ awk -F, '{print $0 (NF<3?FS:"")}' file
entity_name,data_field_name,type
Unit,id,
Track,id,LONG
```